# i get undefined at marker properties

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

i user markerclustererplus and i want to show info window on cluster click. but i get undefined for all marker in a cluster. i just can't figure it out why and what can be happened. here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 95% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r315/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var oncekimarker=null;
    var customIcons = {
      satilik: {
        icon: 'images/pins/yellow.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      kiralik: {
        icon: 'images/pins/blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function initialize() {
        var markers = null;
        var mcmarkers = [];
        var globalMarker = [];

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39, 35),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
          var html = "something";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          mcmarkers.push(marker);

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }

        var mcOptions = {
            gridSize: 30, 
            maxZoom: 13,
            zoomOnClick: false, 
            averageCenter: true
        };

          var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, mcmarkers, mcOptions);
          google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
            var content = '';

            // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
            var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
            info.set('position', cluster.center_);

            //Get markers
            var yazmarkers = cluster.getMarkers();

            var titles = "";
            //Get all the titles
            for(var i = 0; i < yazmarkers.length; i++) {
                titles += yazmarkers[i].name + "\n";
            }
            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setContent(titles); //set infowindow content to titles
            infowindow.open(map, info);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { infowindow.close() });

            });
      });
    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        //infoWindow.open(map, marker);

        if (oncekimarker) oncekimarker.setAnimation(null);
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        oncekimarker = marker;
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    </div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 80%"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

any help whoul be appreciated. thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your markers do not have a "name" property.

```
titles += yazmarkers[i].name + "\n";
```

You can add one by creating them like this

```
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        name: name,
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
```

Warning:  While this works with the API at present, it is not documented behavior, you may want to use the "title" property instead, which is documented and has the benefit of appearing on the Marker as a tooltip on mouseover.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_MarkerClustererPlus.html)